What is the expected lower bound for the Goldbach's function?
The plot below shows the number $g(n)$ of ways to write an even number $n$ as the sum of two primes (sequence A002375 in the OEIS), which is known as the Goldbach's Comet because of its relation to the Goldbach's Conjecture.

The plot seems to suggest we can bound $g$ below by some slowly increasing smooth function $\gamma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ which should follow the bottom edge of the red region. We can approximate it as $\gamma(x)\approx \min\{g(n): N\ge n\ge x\}$ for some large $N$ in order to graph it. For the plot below I used $N = 20000$.

My question is: what is $\gamma$? Of course, I expect no proof for some $\gamma$ to be the correct answer, as this would solve Goldbach's Conjecture. I only want to know what does this function seem to look like, or what is a good guess for it.
One simple heuristic using the Prime Number Theorem gives the total number of ways to write a large even integer $n$ as the sum of two primes to be roughly $\dfrac n{(\log n)^2}$, so maybe $\gamma$ it is a multiple of this function?
Merry Christmas!

A great answer by Greg Martin suggests $2\Pi_2\dfrac n{(\log n)^2}$ as the moral lower bound for Goldbach's comet based on the Extended Goldbach's Conjecture, so I decided to plot them together

It is an amazing fit! However, not quite a lower bound (as predicted by the answer).

@ThomasAndrews what do you mean by "it does not look like a function"?

Ah, I didn't realize the $x$ scale, and it looked like multiple $y$ values for each $x.$

The extended Goldbach conjecture says that the number of ways to write an even number $n$ as the sum of two primes is asymptotic to
$$
2\Pi_2 S(n) \frac n{(\log n)^2}, \quad\text{where } \Pi_2 = \prod_p \biggl( 1 - \frac1{(p-1)^2} \biggr)  \approx 0.66 \text{ and } S(n) = \prod_{\substack{p\mid n \\ p\ne2}} \frac{p-1}{p-2} > 1.
$$
So morally speaking, the lower-bound envelope should be $2\Pi_2 n/(\log n)^2$. (This is unlikely to be precisely true since the conjectured asymptotic formula has an error term.)

This is great! What is the error term? I couldn't find it.

Yeah, heuristics like this tend to just give main terms. We generally feel like the error term should be about $O(\sqrt n)$ if we have no reason to think otherwise (and probably somebody has gathered numerical evidence on the error term as well).
